# Can an 8 bit microcontrollers use a 32 bit Integers? (and the other way around)

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I'm really wondering about the relation of the datasheets and how does this change how thing are done on the programming level,

As far as i know 8 bit in a uC is the resolution of the ADC up to 256 values that signals can be sampled, the higher you go the higher the precision is on the sampled signal however...

Does this affect the code? (Is everything 32bit on the code?)

Whenever I declare an int in a 32bit uC am i actually using an int32? or an int8?

Comment: To me it seems that your title and your description are two more or less different things. For the title the answer is **yes, an 8 bit uC can be do calculation with 32 bit numbers but it will require a number of instructions to do it, i.e. it will be slow**

Comment: It is not even a given that an 8 bit microcontroller has an 8 bit ADC - 10 is probably far more common. It may have no ADC at all.  The width of the ADC has nothing to do with processor architecture - it is about the width of its data bus and core registers..  C is a high level language and generates the necessary machine code  for you - your assumptions about how an 8 bit device handles data is relevant at the machine instruction level - i.e. you'd need to know if you were performing 32 bit operations in assembler for example.

Answer (score 6):

> Can an 8 bit microcontroller use a 32 bit integer?

The short answer is **yes**

When a microcontroller is said to be 8 bit, it means that the internal registers are 8 bit and that the arithmetic unit operates with 8 bit numbers. So in a single instruction, you can only do 8 bit math.

However, you can still do 32 bit math but that will require a number of instructions. For instance, you need 4 8 bit registers to hold a single 32 bit value. Further, you'll have to do the math operation using 8 bit operations (i.e. multiple instructions).

For an **ADD** of two 32 bit int, you'll need four 8 bit add instructions and besides that you'll need instructions to handle carries from the individual add instruction.

So you can do it but it will be slow as a single 32 bit add may require 10-20 instructions (or more - see comment from @YannVernier).

> ... (and the other way around)

AFAIK most 32 bit CPUs have instructions that allows for 8 bit math, i.e. as a single instruction. So doing 8 bit or 32 bit math will will be equally fast (in terms of instructions required).

> Whenever I declare an int in a 32bit uC am i actually using an int32? or an int8?

With a 32 bit CPU, an `int` will normally be 32 bit so the answer is: int32

But from a C standard point of view, it would be okay to have 16 bit `int` on a 32 bit machine. So even if 32 bit would be common, you'll still have to check what the size is on your specific system to be real sure.

Comment: The most extreme case I know offhand for slow wide add is a PIC. mov+add+bcf+3*(btfsc+inc)+mov+add+bcf+2*(btfsc+inc)+mov+add+btfsc+inc+mov+add = 22 instructions(!). Perhaps this is suboptimal, but it's telling.

Comment: @YannVernier Nice example

Comment: The terrifying part is, I dug it out thinking 20 sounded _too high_.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be quite a bit more than one question. First, for the title; yes, 8-bit and 32-bit microcontrollers can typically use integers of either width. Narrower processors will require more steps to handle larger widths, and therefore be slower. Wider processors may lack support for narrower types, causing them to require extra steps as well. Either way, a typical compiler will handle the difference between 8 and 32 bits.

Peripherals such as ADCs can have their own widths; it's not uncommon for them to be a width that doesn't fit precisely in bytes, such as 10 or 12 bits. Successive approximation ADCs also frequently offer a faster mode where less bits hold valid data. In such cases, requesting the fast/narrow mode would require different code from running in slow/full width mode.

If you declare an `int` in a C compliant compiler, you'll never get an 8-bit variable, because C requires it to be at least 16 bits. Many compilers have options to diverge from the standard. On 32 bit computers it frequently is 32 bits, but on a microcontroller it may well be smaller to conserve memory even if the processor is 32 bit. There are width specific types in [`inttypes.h`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/inttypes.h) if you want to be specific.